# How to update the data in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to ask a question about the objective-C and iPhone application. I am writing a program which contains a UITableView *. In the view, it has 1 table section which is 2 rows. Both of the row display a int. In the same page, it has a button. after the user press the button, both of the int will be updated. However, I found that both of the int in the table don't update. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Call `[UITableView reloadData];` to reload the table.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is it just add to some where when I want to update the UITableView?

Comment: Yup. Make the changes and call the function.